# shell command for executing stored procedure in DB2 OS400

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

what is the shell command for executing stored procedure in DB2 OS400.

CALLPRC PRC(SPNAME) PARM('','',5,'','') RTNVAL()

what is this one??

Comment: Are you trying to run a stored procedure from a CL program?  From a QCMD command line?  The command you've included here runs an ILE procedure written in a language such as ILE RPG, which is not the same as a stored procedure.

Comment: actually am not in rpg.. am a php developer. am trying to run sytem command through php. so am searching for system command to execute a stored procedure in DB2 .so the command will be DB2 command line one i hope!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've got a stored procedure called `SPNAME`, here's how you'd run it through SQL on DB2:

```
CALL SPNAME('', '', 5, '', '');
```

This of course assumes that you've already got a database connection through which you can execute SQL statements.

A couple of things you'll probably have to worry about:

1. You will probably have to specify the program's library like this: `CALL LIBNAME.SPNAME(...)`.  Or you can use `SET PATH=LIBNAME` to provide a list of libraries to search.
2. You will want to look into parameter binding.  This will allow you to pass input values to the procedure and get back the output values.

[This link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php) explains how to execute a stored procedure in PHP using ODBC.

Comment: ok thanks.  one quick question. i have a connection file . if i include that here , like just above calling this procedure, it will work?or i have to connect to db using commands

Comment: I am not a PHP guy, so to be honest I'm not sure how it normally works.  I did add a link to my answer which might help.  Good luck!